# jQuery table sorter set default parser for all columns

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I want to set the default parser for every column in my grids to a custom parser I built.  However, I have other columns that have special cases where I built a custom parser for those columns.  I want to simply set the default parser as a custom parser then if I have a second custom parser, that would take precidence if I set it for a specified column. Is this possible?  I do not know if the default parser is 'text' or what?  Thanks!

Comment: you will need to give us some code to look at and to see what your doing. is this tablesorter a plugin your using if so please provide a link

Comment: I am just building a custom parser nothing with to much complexity. I do not have anything public, it is a custom web app running locally. I just want to set the default parser to a custom one. Is this possible? I don't want to specify the columns that it will be using unless I set them. I don't care if I have to manipulate the plugin itself either.

Answer (score 0):

The text parser is the default, but you could add your parser to the first part of the array and override that. It looks like you could modify the tablesorter plugin, and add your custom parser just before the text parser gets added. In jquery.tablesorter.js, you will find this section near the bottom of the plugin:

```
// add default parsers

... add your parser here

ts.addParser({
    id: "text",
    is: function (s) {
        return true;
    }, format: function (s) {
        return $.trim(s.toLocaleLowerCase());
    }, type: "text"
});
```